# Code Golf: XOR Encryption

Tags: encryption, code-golf, xor

**From**: Encryption Co.
**To**: x$*sj4 (that's you)

Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to create a program in the shortest number of keystrokes that

- Takes two filenames parameters (either command line or stdin), the first is a file containing the key and the second some message. Both files will be plain text.
- Applies the key to the message using [XOR encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher), overwriting the file.

**Example:**

Input File:

> StackOverflow is Cool

Key:

> Code Golf

Hex dump of Encrypted Output file:

```
0000000: 101b 0506 4b08 1909 1425 030b 1200 2e1c  ....K....%......
0000010: 4c25 2c00 080d 0a                        L%,....
```

For simplicity, assume files can fit in memory

---

This message will self-encrypt in 5... 4... 3... 2... 1...

```
     #####
    #### _\_  ________
    ##=-[.].]| \      \
    #(    _\ |  |------|
     #   __| |  ||||||||
      \  _/  |  ||||||||
   .--'--'-. |  | ____ |
  / __      `|__|[o__o]|
_(____nm_______ /____\____
```

---

XOR Encryption is impossible to crack if the size of the key is greater or equal to the size of the message and the key is generated by an unbiased random process. See: [One-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). So no "Poor Encryption" here.

Comment: This is the algorithm Yahoo! Messenger uses to encrypt conversations.

Comment: The encrypted output file above decrypts as "StackOverflow is Coolh*".

Comment: Probably a result of the \r\n line endings on Windows.

Comment: No, there's actually a `\r\n` pair at the end of the *encrypted* file. So probably a bug in the OP's implementation :)

Comment: This is actually a great algorithm assuming a random key larger than the message

Comment: "Poor Encryption" is a misnomer. XOR encryption is unbreakable if the size of the key is equal or bigger than the size of the message.

Comment: On a side note, I did a fun project based on "two time pads", the assignment is here: [Class Site](http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~greenie/cs645/), [Project PDF](http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~greenie/cs645/projects/project3.pdf), [Ciphertexts](http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~greenie/cs645/projects/ciphertexts.tar.gz)

Comment: A perfect encryption scheme! Now all we have to do is deliver the random "pad" safely.

Comment: Who's going to do an APL version? (probably in under 10 characters)

Comment: @NULL: ... *and* you **never** reuse the keys, *and* you destroy the key after use *and* you can manage the key distribution...

Comment: Sure there's this one time pad, but poor encryption refers to the fact that if you can transmit the key securely, you can transmit the data securely so why encrypt?

Comment: @Wayne: Because you might only be able to transmit securely during a very short time window. If you know all your messages in advance, you can just send them directly during that time, but if you don't know the messages yet, you can still take advantage of the temporary security to send a sufficiently long key, which you can later use to send and receive encrypted messages after you lose access to the secure channel.

Comment: @bcat If you're reusing a key like this, you're doing it wrong. You're providing more information to the eavesdropper, which causes the encryption to become less secure. You would transmit several keys during the secure phase, and some scheme for selecting between them.

Comment: @Colin: You can use a one-pad cypher to send more than one message, as long as the total length of the messages is shorter than the total length of the cypher and you don't reuse any part of the cypher.

Comment: @Brian: Ah, yes. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 25):

### Repent, <strike>13</strike> 7 chars (No file support), 14 char (With file support)

Repent is an esoteric stack-based toy language of my own, with inspiration from J, APL, Golfscript and Python. Here is a short solution. I will explain it, but is very late and this is doing my head in, so I'll explain it and release a Silverlight interpreter in the morning.

```
↓↷¦*⊕;€
```

Explanation:

```
↓     Copies the message string back onto the stack
↷    Puts the extra message string to the bottom of stack
¦     Find length of message string
*     Multiply key array by last number - repeats key for at least as long as message
⊕;    Apply XOR between each element corresponding of message array and repeated 
      key array, pushing XOR encoded message to stack
€     Print encoded message string/(char array) as string.
```

Use like:

```
Repent "↓↷¦*⊕;€" "Code Golf" "StackOverflow is Cool" > output.txt
```

Output (most chars do not display):

```
Ascii: K    % .L%, 
Hex:   10 1B 05 06 4B 08 19 09 14 25 03 0B 12 00 2E 1C 4C 25 2C 00 08 0D 0A
```

---

Using files it is:

```
↓↶▲⇄▲↓3↔⇄¦*⊕;▼
```

---

[Language reference (unfinished)](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/david.rogers23/Repent/langref.html)

[Interpreter (unfinished)](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/david.rogers23/Repent/interpreter/RepentWebTestPage.html)

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but it could be because your solution doesn't do file IO.

Comment: Oh. OK then. I need to add support for that :(

Comment: +1 for coming up with just another weired upn language of your own that nobody but you read or execute. ;)

Comment: I think you can replace the ¦⇄¦⇄ with 香蕉 吗 ... nobody will understand either :D

Comment: @Yi Jiang WoW! you speak Repent! :D

Comment: These are all valid complaints, I suppose I shouldn't golf with it until I have released it.

Comment: @bel yes we have none of them!

Comment: ...and of course a toy language can trivially solve any problem shorter that a general language: just keep on specializing the language until it's the shortest!

Answer (score 22):

### Perl, 40 char

It's a little fragile.

```
print$/=!1,($_=<>)^substr<>x 1E4,0,y///c
```

Perl has a built-in string xor operator. To solve this problem, the hard part is getting the two strings to have the same length.

```
$/=!1
```

Sets the "record separator" to the undefined value, and doesn't cause anything to be printed. With this setting, the file readline operator will slurp in an entire file.

```
$_=<>
```

Loads the entire first file (containing the message) into the variable `$_`.

```
substr <> x 1E4, 0, y///c
```

Creates another string out of the second file (the key) and adds it to itself 10,000 times. Hopefully, (1) this really long string will be longer than the message string, and (2) it won't be so long that it causes the program to run out of memory (that's how this solution is fragile). `y///c` is an operation to count the number of characters in `$_`, and it's one character shorter than saying `length`. This shortens the key string to the same size as the message string.

Comment: Quite mind blowing. Could you include an explanation for us Perl ignorants ?

Comment: This program doesn't conform to the specifications, it won't overwrite the input message.

Answer (score 12):

**C# 190 characters**

```
using System.IO;class a{static void Main(string[] b){var c=File.ReadAllBytes(b[0]);var d=File.ReadAllBytes(b[1]);for(int e=0;e<c.Length;e++) c[e]^=d[e%d.Length];File.WriteAllBytes(b[0],c);}}
```

Comment: Awesome, at least in the ballpark with Python code. Impressive for .Net verbose languages. :)

Answer (score 8):

**Python, 162 characters**

```
m,r,o=map,raw_input,open
a,b=r(),r()
t,k=m(lambda x:list(o(x).read()[:-1]),[a,b])
o(a,'w').write(''.join(m(chr,m(lambda c:ord(c[0])^ord(c[1]),zip(t,len(t)*k)))))
```

**Python 3, 143 characters**

```
i,o=input,open
a,b=i(),i()
t,k=map(lambda x:list(o(x,'rb').read()[:-1]),[a,b])
o(a,'wb').write(bytes(map(lambda c:c[0]^c[1],zip(t,len(t)*k))))
```

Comment: Epic. I couldn't get mine below 290 :(

Comment: List comprehension is shorter than `map`/`lambda`.

Answer (score 8):

### GolfScript, 28 char

```
n.+/~:k;.,.)k.,@\/)*<{\(@^}%
```

To use, pass the message file, followed by a new line, followed by the key file to the script's standard input:

```
$ (cat message-file ; echo ; cat key-file) | ruby golfscript.rb poorencrypt.gs
```

---

```
$ (echo StackOverflow is Cool;echo;echo Code Golf) | \
          ruby golfscript.rb poorencrypt.gs > encoded-file
$ (cat encoded-file;echo;echo Code Golf) | ruby golfscript.rb poorencrypt.gs
StackOverflow is Cool
```

Comment: It **is possible** to do file IO with Golfscript. see http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Remenber+Previous+Input/gnibbler_1269243311&gs

Answer (score 7):

### Java, <strike>319</strike> <strike>313</strike> 310 chars

---

- **Update 1:** replaced `char[]c=r(a[0]);char[]k=r(a[1]);` by `char[]c=r(a[0]),k=r(a[1]);`, saved 6 chars.
- **Update 2:** replaced `for(int i=0;i<c.length;c[i]^=k[i++%k.length]);` by `int i=0;for(char p:c)c[i]^=k[i++%k.length];`, saved 3 chars.

---

```
import java.io.*;class X{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{char[]c=r(a[0]),k=r(a[1]);int i=0;for(char p:c)c[i]^=k[i++%k.length];Writer w=new FileWriter(a[0]);w.write(c);w.close();}static char[]r(String a)throws Exception{return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a)).readLine().toCharArray();}}
```

More readable version:

```
import java.io.*;
class X{
 public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{
  char[]c=r(a[0]),k=r(a[1]);int i=0;for(char p:c)c[i]^=k[i++%k.length];
  Writer w=new FileWriter(a[0]);w.write(c);w.close();
 }
 static char[]r(String a)throws Exception{
  return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a)).readLine().toCharArray();
 }
}
```

Java IO is pretty verbose. Refactoring two file-to-char[] reads into a method saved 4 chars. Yes, closing (flushing) the writer is absolutely necessary. Else the file is left empty. It would otherwise have been <strike>298</strike> <strike>292</strike> 289 chars.

Comment: +1 for making a serious attempt in java. there's too little in code golf

Comment: i managed to save 3 characters...change the `for loop` to `int i=0;for(char p:c)c[i]^=k[i++%k.length];`

Comment: I was about to scream ripoff, but you take a different approach. +1

Comment: I'm impressed that you got something like this below 500 chars. Java is pretty verbose. +1, of course.

Answer (score 6):

### Python3 - 114 chars

takes parameters from stdin

```
a=input().split()
k,t=[open(x,"rb").read()for x in a]
open(a[1],"wb").write(bytes(x^y for x,y in zip(k*len(t),t)))
```

Comment: +1. So far, yours seems to be the shortest non-esoteric solution that actually conforms to the specification (= overwriting the input file).

Answer (score 4):

## F#, 168 chars

```
open System.IO
[<EntryPoint>]
let main a=
let k=File.ReadAllBytes a.[1]
let z i v=v^^^k.[i%k.Length]
File.WriteAllBytes(a.[0], Array.mapi z (File.ReadAllBytes a.[0]))
0
```

Note: Mostly IO, the key is Array.mapi. Also, some F# Guru will probably beat the hell out of this solution - I am a C# programmer by trade, and never used F# for anything else than learning for fun.

Comment: You can get rid of entrypoint/main/0 and just have the body of main as 'top-level code', which is good code-golf-savings.

Comment: @Brian, I think (based on 2 minutes of googling), that declaring main is the shortest way to get the command line parameters ? Otherwise I'd have to call Environment.GetCommandLineArgs, which is a whole 30 characters. If there is a better way, please correct me :-)

Comment: Oh, I missed that bit - touche!

Comment: Looks good, though I think you switched the command line args around. (The key filename is supposed to come before the message filename.) Also, you need some identation (one space suffices) before the statements in the body of `main`.

Answer (score 4):

**Ruby** <strike>72</strike> 62 chars

```
$<.inject{|k,l|l.each_byte{|b|$><<(b^(r=k.slice!0)).chr;k<<r}}
```

<strike>I could save 10 chars if I didn't have to strip a `\n` from the input key with `k=a.chomp;`</strike>  *Went ahead and did it*

Limitations:  only handles single-line keys.

How it works:

`$<` acts like an array containing all the lines of all the input files.

`.inject` iterates over the array,

`{|k,l|`  : on the first pass, the arguments are the key line, and the first line of the input.

`l.each_byte{|b|` takes each character from the input lines as an int.

`$><<` means "print"

`(b^(r.k.slice!0)` XORs 'b' with the first character in the key (which it slices off and stores in 'r'

`.chr;` converts the integer back to ascii

`k<<r` rotates the first character of the key to the end.

`}}`The block yields the updated k, which will be used as the first argument in the next pass to inject; the 2nd argument will be the next line of input.

Comment: So don't do it. Let the newline be part of the key, or use a key file that doesn't end in a newline.

Comment: The ARGF Object is a adding a newline between the two input files.  I'm stripping it to match the sample result.   If that's not a requirement, I'll be happy to save the 10 chars.

Comment: Also, this puts the output on stdout, you need command line magic to replace the input.  But if golfscript can get away with that, I don't see why ruby can't.

Comment: $><< is just begging for a cutesy name.

Answer (score 4):

Another

## Perl solution, 59 (42) chars

(conforming one-liner that seems to work so far:)

Program (59 chars) with computed key length:

```
 $.-1?$_^=substr($k x((length)/length($k)+1),0,length):$k=$_
```

will be 42 chars if using [mobrule's 'fragile' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478954/code-golf-xor-encryption/3480014#3480014) to key length:

```
 $.-1?$_^=substr($k x 1e4,0,(length)):$k=$_
```

Command Line:

```
 $> perl -i -0777 -pe'<insert above>' keyfile messagefile
```

This **will** rewrite the message to its xor-ed form and back to it's clear text form:

```
 $> cat keyfile ; cat messagefile

 Code Golf
 StackOverflow is Cool
```

Apply command:

```
 $> perl -i.bak -0777 -pe'<insert above>' keyfile messagefile
 $> cat keyfile ; cat messagefile

 Code Golf
 ^P^[^E^FK^H^Y   ^Tl/^@^SEI4O/   e/e
```

Apply again:

```
 $> perl -i.bak -0777 -pe'<insert above>' keyfile messagefile
 $> cat keyfile ; cat messagefile

 Code Golf
 StackOverflow is Cool
```

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 181 chars

I/O is a bitch when golfing in Haskell, and binary I/O doubly so. This solution can probably be vastly improved. Feel free!

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.ByteString as B
u=unpack
g o[l,n]=o$pack$Prelude.zipWith xor(u n)(cycle$u l)
f x=mapM B.readFile x>>=g(B.writeFile$x!!1)
main=Prelude.getLine>>=f.words
```

Usage:

```
$ ghc --make encrypt.hs
$ echo -n 'Code Golf' > key
$ echo -n 'StackOverflow is Cool' > message
$ echo 'key message' | ./encrypt
$ od -tx1 message
```

Comment: Can't you strip of some chars by stripping the `Prelude` prefixes?

Comment: @FUZxxl: No, these functions conflict with identically named functions from `Data.ByteString` (which was designed to be imported qualified). If I recall correctly, importing only the necessary functions turned out to be longer.

Comment: AFAIK, if you imported them with Prefix, you can still call the Prelude functions without prefix, that's why this "prefix import" exists. (I'm really not shure).

Comment: You would think so, but unfortunately not. At least, GHC 6.12.1 rejects it as ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <strike>125</strike> 115 chars

So far, this seems to be the shortest .net-based answer:

```
$k=[char[]](gc $args[1]);$i=0;sc $args[0] ([byte[]]([char[]](gc $args[0])|%{$_ -bXor $k[$i++%$k.Length]})) -en byte
```

Pretty version with command abbreviations spelled out:

```
$k=[char[]](get-content $args[1])
$i=0
set-content `
   $args[0] `
   ([byte[]] ([char[]] (get-content $args[0]) `
              | foreach {$_ -bXor $k[$i++ % $k.Length]})) `
   -encoding byte
```

Usage: `powershell codegolf.ps1 message.txt key.txt`. As requested, it overwrites `message.txt`.

Comment: Shortest .NET solution unless you count IronPython then you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3482453/344286) ;)

Comment: Thanks to Giovanni for informing me about a bug by mail: This breaks if the message contains a line break, since `get-content` won't return a String in that case.

Answer (score 3):

### q, 88 char

Implemented using q from http://kx.com/ which is a language written by Arthur Whitney and inspired by APL and lisp.

```
a[0]1:"x"$2 sv'{(x|y)&not x&y}.'0b vs''flip{y:count[x]#y;(x;y)}.(read1')a:(hsym')`$'.z.x
```

So a little explanation of what is going on: (read Right to Left)

```
a:(hsym')`$'.z.x
```

Creates a list of two file handles from a list of runtime arguments and saves it for later use in variable "a".

```
(read1')
```

Loop over the two files, read them and return a list of list of bytes where byte=0x00..0xFF ((22 bytes),(10 bytes))

```
{y:count[x]#y;(x;y)}.
```

Shape the key to the same length as message.  Key is truncated if too long and repeated if too short.  The list is now well formatted, 2x22.

```
flip
```

Transpose the list and it's now 22x2.

```
0b vs''
```

Convert every element of the list to binary type

```
{(x|y)&not x&y}.'
```

XOR pair wise across all 22 elements, returns a list of list of 8 boolean

```
"x"$2 sv'
```

Convert 8 boolean bits to byte.

```
a[0]1:
```

Write file, overriding original message file.

Sample run:

```
$ cp message.txt message.txt.bk
$ q g.q message.txt key.txt    
$ diff -s message.txt message.txt.bk0
Binary files message.txt and message.txt.bk0 differ
$ q g.q message.txt key.txt          
$ diff -s message.txt message.txt.bk0
Files message.txt and message.txt.bk0 are identical
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby - 158 chars

```
def a(b);File.readlines(b).join("\n").chomp;end;t=a($*[0]);k=a($*[1]);File.open($*[0],"w"){|f|0.upto(t.length-1){|i|f.putc((t[i]^k[i.modulo(k.length)]).chr)}}
```

Prettier version:

```
def a(b)
    File.readlines(b).join("\n").chomp
end

t = a($*[0])
k = a($*[1])

File.open($*[0],"w") {|f|
    0.upto(t.length - 1) {|i|
        f.putc((t[i] ^ k[i.modulo(k.length)]).chr)
    }
}
```

This solution takes advantage of the following aspect of the problem:

> Your mission, should you choose to
>   accept it, is to create a program in
>   the shortest number of *keystrokes*
>   that...

This solution was written on my tablet using handwriting recognition for input.  No keys were stroked in the creation of this code.  Therefore, this program was developed in zero keystrokes.  Game over, I win!

Comment: There are lots of small improvements to be made here: `a=proc{|b|...}` saves 2 over `def a(b);...;end`. -2 for `t,k=$*.map{|f|a(f)}`. -1 for `File.new` instead of open. -2 for `(t.size-1).times` instead of the upto...

Comment: And why would you spell out `modulo` vs `%`?

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 127 chars

uses command line parameters for the keyfile and the datafile

```
import sys
a=sys.argv
_,k,t=[open(x).read()for x in a]
s=open(a[2],"w").write
[s(chr(ord(x)^ord(y)))for x,y in zip(k*len(t),t)]
```

**writing to stdout - 109 chars**

```
import sys
_,k,t=[open(x).read()for x in sys.argv]
print"".join(chr(ord(x)^ord(y))for x,y in zip(k*len(t),t))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java , <s>336</s> <s>316</s> 405 chars

**EDIT:** Forgot that it had to read from a file. *sigh

```
public class A {
public static void main(String[] a) throws Throwable {
    char[] p = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a[1])).readLine().toCharArray();
    char[] t = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a[0])).readLine().toCharArray();
    int u = t.length;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {
        new FileOutputStream (a[0]).write((char) ((int) t[i] ^ (int) p[k]));
        k = k = ++k % p.length;
    }
}
}
```

It was worth a try. However I don't think Java is the best language here...

Comment: `k = k = ++k % p.length;` ?? why not use, this? `k=(k+1)%p.length`

Comment: Also, you don't seem to use `u` in multiple places, so just use `t.length` directly, saves some chars.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < u; i++) { t[i]^=p[i%p.length]; }` then move the `write` outside the loop,

Comment: You can shorten `int` declarations to `int u=t.length,k=0,i=0;`. Further, all those casts are unnecessary.

Comment: +1 I like how the character count gets higher... Why did you leave the newlines/returns, you could golf it a bit more removing all that whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

**Python, 154 characters**

```
import sys,struct;_,f,k=sys.argv
open(f,'r+b').write(''.join(struct.pack('B',ord(a)^ord(b))for a,b in zip(open(f,'r+b').read(),open(k,'rb').read()*1000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### F#, <del>147</del> 146 characters

This is heavily based on [driis's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478954/code-golf-poor-encryption/3479232#3479232). All I did was add the necessary indentation so it compiled, switched the order of the command line parameters, and tightened things up. I wouldn't be surprised if it can still be shortened a little, though. Note: You'll get a warning about incomplete pattern matches. Ordinarily I would be the first to complain about this, but I think code golf deserves an exception to the usual best practices. :)

```
open System.IO[<EntryPoint>]let m[|a;b|]=File.ReadAllBytes|>fun r->r a|>fun k->File.WriteAllBytes(b,Array.mapi(fun i->(^^^)k.[i%k.Length])(r b));0
```

#### F#, 147 characters, more readable

```
open System.IO
let r=File.ReadAllBytes
[<EntryPoint>]
let m[|a;b|]=
 let k=r a
 File.WriteAllBytes(b,Array.mapi(fun i->(^^^)k.[i%k.Length])(r b));0
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <strike>142</strike> 141 characters

**Edit 1:** `fputs()` instead of `fwrite()`.

```
$t=fopen($argv[1],'r+');$s=fgets($t);rewind($t);$k=fgets(fopen($argv[2],'r'));for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++)fputs($t,$s{$i}^$k{$i%strlen($k)});
```

Pretty print:

```
$t = fopen($argv[1],'r+');
$s = fgets($t);
rewind($t);
$k = fgets(fopen($argv[2],'r'));
for($i=0; $i<strlen($s); $i++)
  fputs($t, $s{$i} ^ $k{$i % strlen($k)});
```

Answer (score 0):

## KSH93 - 152 chars

```
m=$(<$1)
k=$(<$2)
for ((e=0;e<${#m};e++)) 
do
out="$out$(printf "%02X" $(("'${m:$e:1}"^"'${k:${e}%${#k}:1}")))"
done
echo "${out}0d0a" | xxd -p -r >$1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java - 306 Chars**

Using BalusC's Java solution as a base:

```
import java.io.*;class X{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{final char[]c=r(a[0]),k=r(a[1]);int i=0;for(int p:c)c[i]^=k[i++%k.length];new FileWriter(a[0]){{write(c);}}.close();}static char[]r(String a)throws Exception{return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a)).readLine().toCharArray();}}
```

More readable:

```
import java.io.*;
class X{
 public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{
  final char[]c=r(a[0]),k=r(a[1]);int i=0;for(int p:c)c[i]^=k[i++%k.length];
  new FileWriter(a[0]){{write(c);}}.close();
 }
 static char[]r(String a)throws Exception{
  return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a)).readLine().toCharArray();
 }
}
```

I didn't actually test the code, but I also didn't change anything drastic.

Answer (score 0):

### C - <strike>163</strike> 161 chars

Added flush and removed unnecessary seek.

**golfed:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int*p,l;char*k;main(int c,char**v){FILE*f=fopen(*++v,"rb+");k=p=*++v;while(fgets(&l,2,f)){fseek(f,-1,1);putc(l^*k++,f);fflush(f);if(!*k)k=p;}}
```

---

**ungolfed:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int*p,l;
char*k;
main(int c,char**v){
    FILE*f=fopen(*++v,"rb+");
    k=p=*++v;
    while(fgets(&l,2,f)){
        fseek(f,-1,1);
        putc(l^*k++,f);
        fflush(f);
        if(!*k)k=p;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can get it shorter using , operator and :? for the if:  ``    while(fgets(&l,2,f))
        fseek(f,-1,1),
        putc(l^*k++,f),
        fflush(f),
        !*k?k=p:0;
`` saving 3 chars

Answer (score 0):

**C#, 168:**

```
using System.IO;class a{static void Main(string[] b){File.WriteAllBytes(b[0],File.ReadAllBytes(b[0]).Select((x,i)=>x^File.ReadAllBytes(b[1])[i%d.Length]).ToArray());}}
```

**A functional solution.** I saved variables by inlining the read operation which causes it to be executed over and over.